# Google compute engine instance rejecting ssh keys

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys, google-cloud-platform, filezilla

I generated my ssh key through the google sdk shell, then i went to put my key in FileZilla and connect to my google compute engine instance and it wont accept my key. How do i fix this?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Naruto it says "Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)" and then on the next line it says "Error: Could not connect to server"

Comment: Some code would be nice aswell..

Comment: @Naruto i just followed google's tutorial on how to transfer files to my lamp server

Comment: @Naruto the tutorial said to type "gcloud compute ssh (name of my instance) --zone (name of my zone)....then i hit enter and my ppk downloaded

Comment: gcloud generated ssh keys are created for the user authenticated at the Developers console when running `gcloud auth login`. You can see that user with `gcloud auth list`. Are you using the same username with filezilla? Are you able to log into the instance via SSH?

Comment: @Antxon i am using the same username and yes i am able to login via ssh

Comment: Are you using Windows? As stated in [FileZilla's wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto) you need [Pageant](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pageant.exe) to SFTP using SSH2.

Comment: @Adrián windows on my laptop and Debian o

Comment: @Adrián debian on my server

Comment: Then, given that you are using Windows on your laptop, you need to run  [pageant](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pageant.exe) (should appear in the system tray) and load the SSH key on it.

Comment: @Adrián im not sure how to use it

Comment: You may also want to try using SSH from the Browser, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser.

Comment: As per the [FileZilla's wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto):

 _Right-click the icon and select "Add Key" and select your private key (PPK) file. Follow the prompt to enter your pass phrase and you're done.
Now simply launch FileZilla and connect to your server using SFTP using SSH2 with a username and an empty password._
Please, if  you are not able to access to your instance, attach some screenshots because they can be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post about it here:

http://blog.sandeepdinesh.com/2015/04/how-to-setup-filezilla-for-google.html

In a nutshell, add the .ppk key to FileZilla (under edit, settings, SFTP). Then connect the the server using the IP address. Make sure the username is right! If the username is not right, it will not work and will reject the key. Run 'whoami' on the remote server to find the username. No need for Pageant.

Comment: A linux command. In the terminal, just type whoami and hit enter.

Comment: i get the same response